# How to use the term "Inline link"?

Tags: grammar, terminology, hyphenation

I am writing a Terms of Service for a website and I am wondering if both of these examples are correct: 
"*Inline* link **to** an image" 
"*In-line* link **of** an image" 
 *Inline linking (also known as hotlinking, leeching, piggy-backing, direct linking, offsite image grabs)*

```
<img src="picture.jpg" />
```

Comment: Both of those are correct, although I think the hyphen in the second sentence is unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah only seen the hyphen version used in a court rule (Perfect 10 v Google) and thought that it was the "official" way of spelling it.

Comment: At the computer magazines where I work, we consistently use the phrase "inline link to an image." If you are in the United States, I don't think you'll startle or bother anyone if you use that wording.

Comment: An "inline link of an image" could be a small image in text that functions as an inline link. Depending on context, "of" can mean composition, possession, apposition (equality), quality, delivering from, linking a result to an original state, and many other things.

Answer (score 1):

[NGrams shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=link+%2a&year_start=1800) that "link between" and "link to" are the most common phrases. "Link between" does not fit appropriately so I recommend "link to". If you restrict the search to "link * an image" than ["to" is clearly the most common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=link+%2a+an+image&year_start=1800).

"Inline" versus "in-line" is following the very common pattern of dropping the hyphen as the term becomes more commonplace. [NGrams shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inline%2C+in-line&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinline%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20-%20line%3B%2Cc0) that "inline" only recently overtook "in-line" in usage.

Therefore, I recommend:

> Inline link to an image